# Swift decodable can't access nested data in array

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I get a critical error stating the following. I've tried everything but I can't seem to access the Movie struct as it says the parent 'Type' has no member called 'data', even though it clearly does.

> "Value of type '[Type?]' has no member 'data'"

MODEL

```
struct SearchData: Decodable  {
     let data: [Type?]
}

struct Type: Decodable  {
     let data: [Movie?]
}

struct Movie: Decodable {
     let title: String?
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
    fileprivate var searchResults = [Movie?]()

    func fetchTitles()  {
    let urlString = "https://www.what-song.com/api/search?limit=10&field=america"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        // if error occurs
        if let err = err    {
            print("Failed to fetch titles", err)
            return
        }
        // if success

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let searchResult =  try JSONDecoder().decode(SearchData.self, from: data)

            self.searchResults = searchResult.data.data

            print(searchResult)

        }   catch   {
            print("Failed to decode JSON:", error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: searchResult.data.data ?

Comment: it's an array , for data in searchResult{...}

Comment: Not immediately important, but what's with that? `SearchResultData` contains an array of `SearchResultType`? That's really unclear naming, only made worse by the fact that you end up writing things like `searchResult.data.data`.

Comment: Yeah I agree the naming is not that great, but you have to understand that searchResult is an array, and does not contain data, but each of his element does.

Comment: Hmm ok, I think I understand. I have renamed the structs above to make it more clear. Unfortunately I can't rename the JSON 'data' endpoints, even though I agree, it is poor practice. How would I go about printing just the Movie 'title' properties then?

Comment: @unicorn_surprise You can (and should) define custom coding keys so that you can avoid having your Swift identifiers being forcefully determined by the choices made by the JSON API designers (who have different priorities in mind, mainly terseness to save space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
var movieTitles = [String]()

for type in searchResult.data {
   for movie in type.data {
       guard let title = movie.title else { return }
       print(title)
       movieTitles.append(title)
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes that works :) All titles are being printed to console now. Thank you so much.

Also, again, sorry for being such an amateur, but then how to set the searchResults variable at the top to the array of Movies generated in the for loop. 

self.searchResults = [movie]

Comment: no worries ;), if it works click on the green check ;) I want some points !!

Comment: Thanks mate. Any idea on the setting of self.seachResults though? 

For some reason `self.movieResults = [movie]` is only setting one movie instead of the whole iterated array.

Answer (score 2):

you are doing a small mistake here I think

> searchResult.data

will return you an array of

> Type

You need to parse that array as well, something like this

```
            searchResults = (searchResult.data[0]?.data)!
```